# error: Tried to get a variable "sections" which is not stored in the context

Tags: typo3

i have installed
TYPO3 7.6.12 and
fluidcontent 4.4.1
fluidpages 3.6.1
flux 7.4.0

I have the error
"Tried to get a variable "sections" which is not stored in the context" in the frontend after clearing the cache.

I have read this:
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/72231

But i do not understand this error and don't know how to debug it.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you selected Fluidpages as backend layout then you have to choose a Fluidpage layout in your page properties.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your template is missing an entry for a section, something like {content}